# Error con Ñ en char en java

Tags: java, java-8

Utilizo el visual code para hacer un arreglo de tipo `char`, al agregar `Ñ` me da un error, está el formato en utf8.

Este es mi código:

```
public class App {
    char[] chars = {'n', 'ñ'};
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Hello Java");
    }
}
```

Error:

> Invalid character constantJava(1610612989)

Comment: Tu programa corre perfectamente con codificación utf-8, posiblemente en tu editor de texto o IDE lo guardaste con otra codificación. Puedes reproducir el error convirtiendo a ISO-8859-1 y de vuelta a UTF-8, lo más probable es que tu código tenga el BOM y solamente deberás borrar y re-escribir la ñ y guardarlo como utf-8

Comment: Que IDE estas usando @GuzL ?

Comment: Visual studio Code, pero el mismo codigo me funciona en netbeans...

Answer (score 2):

Sustituye la ñ mediante unicode.

```
char[] chars = {'n', '\u00f1'};
```

O mediante su valor ASCII.

```
char[] chars = {'n', 164};
```

Comment: Pero si quisiera trabajar directamente, que codificación debo poner? en lugar de utf8

Comment: UTF-8 está bien ya que te permite utilizar los caracteres del idioma español

Comment: Java igual que cualquier otro lenguaje de programación, margina a la gente que utiliza carácteres extendidos para la escritura, por lo que por defecto no permite que haya acentos ni eñes en el código.

De todas maneras, podemos forzar la escritura de estos carácteres no soportados mediante unicode

Comment: Si lo que quieres es utilizar de todas maneras char[] chars = {'n', 'ñ'}; puedes utilizar otros IDE's que ya están preconfigurados, pero  si lo que quieres es continuar con Visual Studio Code, te tocará cambiar la configuración de tu SO.